# What is the value of $m+n$??

Tags: probability, permutations

Suppose that there are $5$ red points and $4$ blue points on a circle . Let $\frac{m}{n}$ be the probability that a convex polygon whose vertices are among the 9 points has at least one blue vertex when $m$ & $n$ are relatively prime. Then the value of $(m+n)$ is?

This question came in recent JEE Advanced (unofficial) test and I'm stumped on how to approach this problem. The answer given is $460$ .

I'm new to geometric probability and permutational concepts.
Please someone help me out on how to approacch this problem.

Comment: A few of us have gotten $458$.  It's possible we all missed something, but is there any chance the given answer is wrong?

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, Its a possibility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(# convex polygons)= (# subsets of 9-element set of size 3 or more) = 
    $512 -(36+9+1) = 466$.

(# all red polygons) = (# subsets of 5-element set of size 3 or more) = $10+5+1 = 16$.

So, $ m/n = (466 - 16) / 466 = 450/466 = 225/233 $

Thus, I get  $ m + n = 458 $

Not sure where I miscalculated :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that a convex plolygon has at least three vertices the overall number of the convex polygons is

$$2^9-C_2^9-C_1^9-1=466,$$
where $C^i_j$ are the binomial coefficients.

From those

$$2^5-C_2^5-C^5_1-1=16$$

have only red vertices.

Thus the probability $m/n$ is $(466-16)/466=450/466=225/233$ and $m+n=458$.

Comment: Isn't $2^9- {9 \choose 2} - {9 \choose 2} -1 = 466$ ?

Comment: You have an arithmetical error; the first value should be $466$, not $476$.  At least as far as I can tell.  Unfortunately, that leads to the same answer that the other answers and I have arrived at, which is $458$, not $460$.